# How can I "simulate" merge of code on Bitbucket PR

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

We work with Bitbucket and Jenkins. When pull request is created a web-hook is triggered in order to test the code. However since the code is still not merged I have only the feature branch code cloned to Jenkins.
How can I "simulate" the merge and run tests before actually merge to the mainline branch? Is it possible to do temporary merge via Bitbucket only and not via code merge manipulation on Jenkins node?

Answer (score 0):

There are to main ways to work with branches and Jenkins, using a [Multi Branch Pipline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) and the second option is to use a custom made job. Let's examine both options:

In a Multi branch pipeline you just need to set the configuration you want and the hooks and merge options will be done by the plugin.
When you configure your project, in the *Behaviors* section (discover options) when you select the option **Discover pull requests from origin** , which mean pull request on the repository will trigger builds, you need to select the *Strategy*, the option you need is:

> **Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision**
> Discover each pull request once with the discovered revision
> corresponding to the result of merging with the current revision of
> the target branch

Choosing this option means that when a pull request is created, the pipeline will checkout the result of the branch you want to merge with the current version of the merge target - which is exactly what you want for your tests - a simulation of the future merge outcome that can be tested before the merge.

[image]

---

In the second option you are using a regular or a pipeline job that is triggered by a pull request and you are handling the Git clone by yourself, in that case the git plugin has ad advance behavior that allows you to merge while cloning the repository.
So when you use the checkout git SCM step there is an **Additional Behaviours** section, in it there is an option called *Merge before build*:

> **Merge before build**:
> These options allow you to perform a merge to a particular branch
> before building. For example, you could specify an integration branch
> to be built, and to merge to master. In this scenario, on every change
> of integration, Jenkins will perform a merge with the master branch,
> and try to perform a build if the merge is successful. It then may
> push the merge back to the remote repository if the Git Push
> post-build action is selected.

In a pipeline job this step will look like the following:

```groovy
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'PR_BRANCH']], 
         extensions: [[$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [mergeTarget: 'master']]], 
         userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'GIT_CREDS', url: 'GIT_URL']]])
```

In the UI it will look like:
[image]

In both cases you will get your desired behavior: the outcome of the future merge that can be tested prior to the actual merge.